# Django serializer read and write multiple model field with

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

How to read and write multiple models in Django rest framework Model Serializer. like I have created a user-create model view set API, for that, I create a Model Serializer. there I need to give multiple permissions. for that, I pass the user_permissions field with an array of permission's id. now, how can I define a field in the user Model Serializer that can create a user with this permission and then get the user with permission's data?

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AbstractUser
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True},}
        extra_fields = ['user_permissions']

#view
class RegistrationView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = AbstractUser.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)
    permission_classes_by_action = [IsAdminUser, ]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response_data = super(RegistrationView, self).create(request,*args,**kwargs)
        return Response({"data": response_data.data})
```

request body

```
  {
   "username": "testuser",
   "email": "testuser@example.com",
   "first_name": "test",
   "last_name": "test",
   "password": "Abcd@123456",
   "user_permissions": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  }
```

required response

```
{
"id": 1,
"email": "testuser@example.com",
"username": "testuser",
"first_name": "test",
"last_name": "test",
"is_superuser": false,
"is_staff": false,
"is_active": true,
"date_joined": "2022-08-17T10:25:48.446821Z",
"user_permissions": [
    {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Can add User",
            "codename": "add_user",
            "content_type": "account"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Can change User",
            "codename": "change_user",
            "content_type": "account"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Can delete User",
            "codename": "delete_user",
            "content_type": "account"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Can view User",
            "codename": "view_user",
            "content_type": "account"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Can view log entry",
            "codename": "view_logentry",
            "content_type": "admin"
        }
],
"groups": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> now, how can I define a field in the user Model Serializer that can create a user with this permission and then get the user with permission's data?

You can override the [create()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations) method in Serializer Class

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    instance = super().create(validated_data) #save instance first
    for permission_id in validated_data['user_permissions']:
        ... #do something for associate user_permission to user
    return instance
```

I have some doubts about `extra_fields = ['user_permissions']`.
I think you have to add a [ListField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) in serializer named *user_permissions*, in this way the serializer recognize the field, validate it and you can find the field in validated_data dictionary.